# Batch-File. Iterative directory search excluding one

Tags: batch-file

I have this folder tree:

```
C:\A
C:\A\Sub
C:\B\
C:\B\Sub
C:\Moved
```

if I write in CMD this code it works:

```
dir /ad /on /b /s | findstr /v "Moved"
```

it shows all directories except `/Moved`

```
C:\A
C:\A\Sub
C:\B\
C:\B\Sub
```

but when I try to use it in Batch-File it doesn't work:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /on /b /s | findstr /v "Moved"') do (
      ...
      myCode
      ...
)
```

I don't know what is wrong.
Some help?
Thank You.

Comment: This is not a batch file exclusive issue, if you also ran the `for` loop in cmd, the issue would still persist. See @Compo's comment. The issue pervades through both cmd and batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously my comment, *(now removed)*.

You need to escape the pipe character, **`|`**, with a caret, **`^`**, because the content within the parentheses is passed to another instance of `cmd.exe`, and when passed to it, you want the pipe to be processed in that instance, not when being passed to it.

You could do the task using `find.exe` if you wish to exclude directories with names containing the case insensitive string `Moved`:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%I In ('Dir /B/S/ON/AD^|%__AppDir__%find.exe /I /V "Moved"')Do @(…)
```

Or beginning with the case insensitive string `Moved`:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%I In ('Dir /B/S/ON/AD^|%__AppDir__%find.exe /I /V "\Moved"')Do @(…)
```

Or even to include `Moved` but ignore any subdirectories of it:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%I In ('Dir /B/S/ON/AD^|%__AppDir__%find.exe /I /V "\Moved\"')Do @(…)
```

---

You could of course still use `FindStr` as in your provided example.

To do it using the `Dir` command piped to `findstr.exe` and this time omit any directory which is case insensitively named `Moved`:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%I In ('Dir /B/S/ON/AD^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /IV "[\\]Moved[\\] [\\]Moved$"')Do @(…)
```

However your directories will not be listed in true alphabetical order.

---

As an alternative, you could use the `RoboCopy` command from your `For` loop. This will output your directories in a true alphabetical order, suffixing each with a trailing backslash:

```batch-file
@For /F "Skip=2Tokens=*" %%I In ('%__AppDir__%robocopy.exe . NULL /E /L /NC /NFL /NJH /NJS /NS /XD Moved 2^>NUL')Do @(…)
```

---

**In all examples replace `…` with your own command(s)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `^` before `|`, like this:

```
dir /ad /on /b /s ^| findstr /v "Moved"'
```